# Matlab import binary as matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file that contains a data like this:

```
0000000011111000
0000001110001110
0000011000011111
0001110000000001
0011000000000001
0011000000000001
0110000000000001
0100000000000001
1100000000000001
1100000000000001
1000000000000001
1100000000000010
1100000000000110
0100000000001100
0110000000011000
0011111111110000
0
//repeats like this
```

The 0 at the end is a label that describes the 16x16 matrix of 0's and 1's. As you can see it is actually a binary image of 0.

I need to load this file as a 16x16 matrix. I have tried `importdata`, `textscan`and `fscanf` but none worked for me.

The file continues in this format.

My initial tought was to use '' as a delimiter for `importdata`, but that did not worked.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Read each line as a text and convert it via `bin2dec`? What output do you expect?

Comment: why would these functions not work for you? Matlab does not support give so many ways to handle bitmaps, I think that you need to read it as a string and then convert it to numerics. I assume that the 0 in the end is there to indicate end of file, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to read the file (see [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html?refresh=true) for some documentation):

```
fid=fopen(textfile);
dat = textscan(fid,'%s',-1);   % <-- read into cell array of strings
fclose(fid);

dat=char(dat);    % <-- concatenate the strings into one char array
dat = double(dat)- '0'; % <-- convert to numeric 0/1 (48 = '0'+0)
```

The last row will contain the number represented ("0") and superfluous stuff, you can delete with e.g. `dat(end,:)=[];`
Happy trails!

---

Edit: Although the posted answer works with the input text file and input method I used, for the OP the code requires modification (probably due to a difference in input format):

```
i = 1 : length (dat{1,1}) 
   result(i,:) = double(char(dat{1,1}{i,1})) - '0';
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that almost worked! the first row is stored in dat{1,1}{1,1}. So if you can update the snipplet with 
for i = 1 : length (dat{1,1})
   result(i,:) = double(char(dat{1,1}{i,1})) - '0';  
end    I will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @wrecker So you do not use the line `dat=char(dat)`? The code I posted works perfectly for me, what error are you getting when you run it?

Comment: it gives the following error "Error using char
Cell elements must be character arrays."

Comment: yeap just as your answer, agreed pretty odd